# Julia MongoDB save raw variable

Tags: mongodb, variables, save, julia

I would like to save some variables in Julia to a database using MongoDB. I ran into a problem when using the following function:

```
insert(client, "myDB.rawInfo", { "raw" => status})
```

This works when saving simple information, like strings or ints. However, status is of type Array{Any,1}. When saving, I get the following error message:

```
`build` has no method matching build(::Ptr{None}, ::Dict{String,Any})
while loading In[256], in expression starting on line 18
in append at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\BSON.jl:225
in append at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\BSON.jl:231 (repeats 2 times)
in build at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\BSON.jl:207
in BSONObject at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\BSON.jl:82
in find_one at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\Mongo.jl:30
in find_one at C:\Users\Guido\.julia\v0.3\Mongo\src\Mongo.jl:34
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This may get more attention by the right sorts of folks if you post it as an issue over at [Mongo.jl](https://github.com/Lytol/Mongo.jl/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the MongoDB package for Julia which causes the malfunction of nested variables. A fix has been made a while ago and can be applied by manually reinstalling this version of MongoDB for Julia (first uninstall, than manually reinstall): https://github.com/rened/Mongo.jl